# Pass parameter in the eventhandler from ascx to aspx in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a search button in usercontrol "header", i want to pass the text in the searchbox to a aspx page. I am using EventHandler for that purpose but i'm confused on how to pass the parameter along with `searchBtn`.

```
public event EventHandler searchBtn;

public void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchText = tb_search.ToString();
        searchBtn(sender,e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define custom EventArgs. Let's say:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> searchBtn;

public void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myEventArgs = new MyEventArgs(){ SearchText = tb_search.ToString()};        
    searchBtn(sender,myEventArgs);
}

public class MyEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public string SearchText {get;set;}
}
```